# Get multiple fields from aws cloudtrail json using jq

Tags: json, jq

I need to extract some fields from below json. This is from aws cloudtrail, and I'm having a really hard time figuring this out.

The fields I need are:

```
userIdentity.userName
eventTime
awsRegion
sourceIPAddress
responseElements.ConsoleLogin
eventID
```

JSON

```
{
  "eventVersion": "x.xx",
  "userIdentity": {
    "type": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "principalId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "arn": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "userName": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "eventTime": "2020-07-15T08:50:35Z",
  "eventSource": "signin.amazonaws.com",
  "eventName": "ConsoleLogin",
  "awsRegion": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "sourceIPAddress": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "userAgent": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "requestParameters": null,
  "responseElements": {
    "ConsoleLogin": "Success"
  },
  "additionalEventData": {
    "LoginTo": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "MobileVersion": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "MFAUsed": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "eventID": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "eventType": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "recipientAccountId": "xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: What did you try? You can literally spell out the required fields inside `jq` with a dotted notation before the field names?

Comment: I think I actually figured this out. jq '.userIdentity.userName, .eventTime, .awsRegion, .sourceIPAddress, .responseElements.ConsoleLogin, .eventID'. Simplest solutions are best...

Answer (score 0):

```
aws --region <region> cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=ConsoleLogin --max-items 1 --output json | \
jq -r .Events[].CloudTrailEvent | \
jq '.userIdentity.userName, .eventTime, .awsRegion, .sourceIPAddress, .responseElements.ConsoleLogin, .eventID'
```

Comment: There’s no need to call jq twice! Use jq’s `|` instead.